# Как осуществить посик в переменной для получения строки

Tags: поиск, переменные, ansible

Всем привет, есть проблема с Ansible. 
Есть PlayBook следующего содержания:

```
 tasks:
      - name: ask enclsure info
        raw: SHOW enclosure info
        register: showResult
```

Где я собственно получаю информацию и переписываю её в переменную.
Информация в таком виде представлена:

```
    TASK [show result findings] 
    ok: [Onboard] => {
    "showResult.stdout_lines": [
        "SHOW enclosure info", 
        "", 
        " BladeSystem Onboard Administrator", 
        "(C) Copyright 2006-2017", 
        "",  
        "", 
        "", 
        "Enclosure Information:", 
        "\tEnclosure Name: AlphaServer_emulator", 
        "\tEnclosure Type: BladeSystem", 
        "\tPart Number: 68661", 
        "\tSerial Number: CZ332", 
        "\tUUID: 09CZ3328JJF8", 
        "\tAsset Tag: ", 
        "\tMidplane Spare Part N001", 
        "\tSolutions ID: 0000000000000000", 
        "\tPower Distribution Unit:", 
        "\t\tPDU Type: HP AC Module, Single Phase, Intlgnt", 
        "\t\tPDU Spare Part Number: 666226-001", 
        "\tOnboard Administrator Tray Information:", 
        "\t\tType: Administrator Tray", 
        "\t\tSpare Part Number: 711901", 
        "\t\tSerial Number: OA32    ", 
        "", 
        "", 
        "OA-10604BB20D13 [SCRIPT MODE]> ", 
        ""
    ]
}
```

И вот нужно мне из этой переменной, вытащить одну строку где есть слово "Serial Number:" то есть именно (CZ332), это значение мне нужно поместить в другую переменную соответвенно.
Ни как не могу найти как осуществить поиск в переменной, так же нужно будет применять регулярные выражения?
Всем заранее спаибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, нужно применить фильтр поиска по регулярному выражению: [regex_search](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters).

Например,

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ showResult.stdout | regex_search('Serial Number: (\\S+)','\\1') }}"
```

Значение серийного номера в данном случае будет первой группой, которую мы просим у фильтра вторым параметром.
Бэкслеши экранированы, т.к. мы находимся внутри двойных кавычек.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло. Искал кучу времени!

Comment: А так же вопрос, как потом msg поместить в другую переменную?

Comment: Уж простите, но этот вопрос я проигнорирую. Поищите `set_fact`.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо что направили на правильный путь, хоть вопрос конечно задал и не правильно немного.

Comment: Продолжаю борьбу, может Вы знаете, я использовал ваше решение в set_fact, и все бы прошло успешно, если бы не один момент. С фильтром который Вы предлагаете, добавляються квадратные скобки и буква u. И теперь это выглядит так:   `"serialNumberEnclosure": "'[u'CZ332']'" `, подскажите как этого избежать, нужно просто строка серийного номера? Если конечно не трудно. Буду признателен.